# Heroku multi-threading

Tags: python, heroku

I am making a website with heroku and now I'm making a task that will run in the background
Something like this:

```py
def task():
    while True:
        ...
        # some task that will run in the background
```

And in my file `app.py`, I have this code:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Thread(target=app.run).start()
    Thread(target=task).start()
```

I've put some `print` in the task function (something like `print("Task started")`
But in the heroku log I only saw flask started message and no task message, not even an error, and the things that should happen in the task function doesn't happen. And I try to run the flask app in my local machine and it works.

So how to fix this?

Comment: Is this task meant to run in the background continuously?

Comment: @Chris yep.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" way to do this on Heroku is to define your background task as a separate process, e.g. by doing something like this in your `Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
worker: python path/to/background_task.py
```

Now you can [scale up a dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-ps-scale) to run the `worker` process:

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

There are [lots of benefits to this approach](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/process-model), but it does mean you need to have at least two dynos running. That either costs money or consumes free dyno hours at a faster rate.

Comment: I have one question, `worker: python background_task.py` Where should I place the file `background_task.py`? And does this mean that I don't need to do `Thread(target=task).start()` ?

Comment: You can put it wherever you want, just update your `Procfile` accordingly. I've updated my answer to clarify. And yes, this would replace your call to `Thread()`.